# Cannot create bootable file

Tags: boot

I'm new to Linux and Ubuntu having become heartily sick of Windows 10 not performing as advertised and shutting me out for an hour or more whenever it decides to burden me with yet another update. I've downloaded the 18.04LTS iso file but cannot convert it to a bootable file. I've got some software called ISOtoUSB, when I try to burn to a USB drive it fails every time with the message that it "cannot create a bootable file". Is there something better than the ISOtoUSB out there, or is this yet another example of W10 not working?

Comment: The iso was born to be primarily for CD/DVD installation. You can "burn" an iso to a USBStick as explained in the [official help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

Comment: Make sure your USB drive is big enough.